# chrome and IE prints two blank pages after my content page, in FireFox it works fine

Tags: javascript, html, css

My css is

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden !important;
        height: auto;
    }

    #printSection, #printSection * {
        visibility: visible !important;
        page-break-inside: auto !important;
        page-break-after: avoid !important;
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
    }

    #printSection {
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        page-break-inside: auto !important;
        page-break-after: avoid !important;
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
    }

    #printContent {
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
        page-break-after: avoid !important;
    }
}

and my HTML is

<div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="divHeader">

        </div>
        <div id="divSubHeader">
            <table width="100%" style="height: 30px;" class="h1">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Performance Report
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div id="divContent">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl" width="20%">EMP-Name
                    </td>
                    <td>


                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">



                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" class="lbl" style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl" width="20%"> R.No.
                    </td>
                    <td>


                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">

    enter code here
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" class="lbl" style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl" width="20%">ID
                    </td>
                    <td>



                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">


                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" class="lbl" style="padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;">                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lbl" width="100%" style="text-align: center;" colspan="4">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>

    </div>
```

This work fine for me in firefox and while doing same html and css in chrome,IE it adds two more blank pages after my content page which is only half length of A4 size in content. I want no more extra pages please help.